# Can Django ORM do an ORDER BY on a specific value of a column?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have a table 'tickets' with the following columns

- id - primary key - auto increment
- title - varchar(256)
- status - smallint(6) - Can have any value between 1 and 5, handled by Django

When I'll do a `SELECT *` I want the rows with `status = 4` at the top, the other records will follow them. It can be achieved by the following query:

```
select * from tickets order by status=4 DESC
```

Can this query be executed through Django ORM? What parameters should be passed to the `QuerySet.order_by()` method?

Comment: you are not ordering, you are filtering (SQL WHERE clause).

Comment: @stefanw - It would be called filtering if ONLY wanted records with status=4, which I don't.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
q = Ticket.objects.extra(select={'is_top': "status = 4"})
q = q.extra(order_by = ['-is_top'])
```

Comment: I upvoted this for its neatness, but later noticed a note in the docs saying that .extra() is scheduled to be deprecated. Can this be accomplished another way, e.g. with Annotate? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Answer (score 15):

I did this while using PostgresSql with django.

```
from django.db.models import Case, Count, When

Ticket.objects.annotate(
    relevancy=Count(Case(When(status=4, then=1)))
).order_by('-relevancy')
```

It will return all objects from Ticket, but tickets with status = 4 will be at the beginning.

Hope someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 8):

For those in need just like me that stumbled on this now and are using newer versions of Django

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

Ticket.objects.annotate(
    relevancy=Case(
        When(status=4, then=1),
        When(status=3, then=2),
        When(status=2, then=3), 
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('-relevancy')
```

Using Count() will return 1 or 0 depending if your case was found or not. Not ideal if ordering by a couple of status

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple a `.annotate()` to add a True or False value for any given condition. In this case `status = 4` is the first `order_by` parameter, but it could be combined with any additional conditions.

```
from django.db.models import Q

tickets = Tickets.objects.all() ## Or .filter(**Your ciriteria**)
tickets = tickets.annotate(
     priority1=Q(status=4),
     priority2=Q(**Some Other Condition**),
     [...]
     )

tickets = tickets.order_by("-priority1", "-priority2", [...])
```