# Django concatenate two querysets for same model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a list of `Products`, each belonging to a different `Distributor`.

I need to display a form for each of those products and their corresponding distributor. I can do so with this code:

```
form_products = ProductFormSet(
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(product__id=product_id)
)
```

The problem is that I need to display the form with the product belonging to a particular `Distributor` named "FirstDistributor" **first** in the page.

I tried to do so with the following code using the | operator between the querysets:

```
form_products = ProductFormSet(
    queryset=(
        Product.objects.filter(
            product__id=product_id, 
            distributor__name='FirstDistributor') | 
        Product.objects.filter(
            product__id=product_id
        ).exclude(distributor__name='FirstDistributor')
    )
)
```

But the forms are still displayed in the same order. How can I concatenate those two querysets into one, while keeping the same order?

```
q1 = Product.objects.filter(product__id=product_id,
    distributor__name='FirstDistributor')
```

and

```
q2 = Product.objects.filter(product__id=product_id
    ).exclude(distributor__name='FirstDistributor')
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Queryset class implements the iterator interface so it can be used as that, hence the **itertools.chain** method can be used to combine multiple querysets of the the same model together

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do it like here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176471/4971083

It's the solution for ordering your records by specific value in Django.
You could order your records by distributor_name = 'FirstDistributor'

```
p= Product.objects.filter(product__id=product_id).extra(
select={'is_top': " distributor__name='FirstDistributor'"})
p = p.extra(order_by = ['-is_top'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools to combine the two:

```
from itertools import chain
result_list = list(chain(page_list, article_list, post_list))
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/434755/3279262