# Ordering Django queryset using attributes of a JSONField, provided the attribute is not present everywhere

Tags: django, django-orm, django-jsonfield

This is a very complex question, so let me explain. I have a model called Person which stores most of its data in a JSONField.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

Now, the data field is usually in the the following format:

```
{"name" : <String>, "age" : <int>}
```

Now, what I want to do is create a queryset of Person, that orders the objects using the `age` attribute from its `data` field, in descending order. This is solved using the following code:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
from .models import Person

qs = Person.objects.annotate(age=RawSQL("(data->>'age')::int", [])).order_by('-age')
```

This is great, and works well. However, during testing, I changed the `data` attribute of one Person object to something like this:

```
{"name" : <String>, "profession" : <String>}
```

That is, this object does not have the `age` attribute, within its `data` field. Now when I run the query above, it still works fine, but this object (the one without `age` attribute), is at the very top. This is because of one of two reasons:

- Since its `age` is null, its sent to the top because of the descending order_by function.
- Its the object I last created, so it was always at the beginning, but because it does not have the `age` attribute, its simply not being affected by the order_by function, and it stays in its original position.

**What I actually want to do is send all the objects that don't have the `age` attribute in their `data` field to the very end of the queryset.**

I tried the union method by creating 2 querysets(one where age is not null, and one where it is) and joined them using `|` operator. This did not work because the ordering got messed up. I also tried this weird method I found in another question (which also did not work):

```
qs = Person.objects.annotate(age=RawSQL("(data->>'age')::int", [])).extra(select={'is_top': "age__isnull=True"})
qs = qs.extra(order_by('-is_top')
```

[Link to the weird solution that did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176346/can-django-orm-do-an-order-by-on-a-specific-value-of-a-column/2176471#2176471)

Anyway, is there any way to do this that does not involve lists, itertools, and chains? Because I have heard they can be pretty slow at times.

Thanks!

*Note: Please no answers about normalizing the database for these queries instead of using JSONFields. I am well aware on the benefits of normalization, but for my use case, it has to be a JSONField.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the key lookup fails, the result is `NULL` as specified in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):

> Note: There are parallel variants of these operators for both the json and jsonb types. The field/element/path extraction operators return the same type as their left-hand input (either json or jsonb), except for those specified as returning text, which coerce the value to text. The field/element/path **extraction operators return `NULL`, rather than failing, if the JSON input does not have the right structure to match the request**; for example if no such element exists.

You *can* do that, you simply order with [**`.desc(nulls_last=True)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values):

```
from django.db.models import F, RawSQL
from .models import Person

qs = Person.objects.annotate(
    age=RawSQL("(data->>'age')::int", [])
).order_by(F('age').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

This will order the elements by:

```
-- SQL query
ORDER BY age IS NULL, age DESC
```

So by first ordering by `age IS NULL`, this will result in `TRUE`, and as a result, it is ordered at the *bottom* of the result table.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.